# Как лучше объединить три простых MySQL запроса в один сложный?

Tags: mysql

Есть три простых MySQL запроса:

```
SELECT id_city, id_region, id_country FROM cities WHERE city_name_ru LIKE '$city1'

SELECT country_name_ru FROM countries WHERE id_country = '$country'

SELECT region_name_ru FROM regions WHERE id_region = '$region'
```

Каждый запрос зависит от предидущего запроса. Вопрос - Как лучше объединить три простых MySQL запроса в один сложный?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так

```
SELECT t.id_city , t.city_name_ru, 
       c.id_country,  c.country_name_ru, 
       r.id_region, r.region_name_ru 
FROM cities AS t, countries AS c, regions AS r
WHERE t.city_name_ru LIKE "% '.$city1.'%"
  AND t.id_country = c.id_country
  AND t.id_region = r.id_region
```

не проще?

Answer (score -2):

мой вариант:

```
SELECT t.`id_city`, t.`full_name`, t.`country_name_ru`,t.`city_name_ru`
                FROM (
                 SELECT 
                  ci.`id_city` AS `id_city`,
                  ci.`id_region` AS `id_region`,
                  ci.`id_country` AS `id_country`,
                  re.`region_name_ru` AS `region_name_ru`,
                  co.`country_name_ru` AS `country_name_ru`,
                  CONCAT(co.`country_name_ru`, ", ", re.`region_name_ru`) AS `full_name`
                 FROM 
                  `cities` AS ci,
                  `regions` AS re,
                  `countries` AS co
                 WHERE
                  ci.`id_region` = re.`id` AND
                  re.`id_country` = co.`id`
                 ORDER BY ci.`id` ASC
                ) AS t
                WHERE t.`city_name_ru` LIKE "% '.$city1.'%" OR t.`id_country` = '.$country.' OR  t.`id_region` = '.$region.'
                LIMIT 20
```

добавил full_name, еще city_name_ru. Попробуйте должно сработать, сам не протестировал

Comment: Ну да и так можно, только у меня есть связка, можно выводить и по имени и по ид страны и по ид региона т.е. все они друг друга не зависит т.е. можно выводить например имея только региона.